# How to use genrules with go:embed

Tags: go, bazel

I need to include some generated files (for example output from go-swagger) in a binary. Without bazel you can do that using `go:generate` in combination with `go:embed`:

```golang
package demo
//go:generate swagger generate spec -w . -o ./openapi.json

import "embed"

// Content contains openapi.json file generated via go-swagger from spec
//go:embed openapi.json
var Content embed.FS
```

I am trying to do the same thing with bazel. As a simple test I have have this `BUILD.bazel` file:

```
genrule(
    name = "hellodata",
    srcs = ["hello.go"],
    outs = ["hello.txt"],
    cmd = "cat $(SRCS) | tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m > $@",
)

go_library(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hello.go"],
    importpath = "wiggy.net/hello",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    embedsrcs = [":hellodata"],
)
```

with `hello.go` looking like this:

```golang
package hello

import (
    _ "embed"
    "io"
)

//go:embed hello.txt
var greeting []byte

func Hello(out io.Writer) error {
    _, err := out.Write(greeting)
    return err
}
```

The intention here is to have `Hello` output the rot13 of it's own source. When I try to compile this it successfully generates `hello.txt` (located in `bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/hello.txt`), but the compiler can not find it:

```
❯ bazel build //...                              
INFO: Analyzed 5 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 5 targets...
ERROR: /Users/wichert/Hack/bzl/BUILD.bazel:14:11: GoCompilePkg hello.a failed: (Exit 1): builder failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/external/go_sdk/builder compilepkg -sdk external/go_sdk -installsuffix darwin_arm64 -src hello.go -embedsrc bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/hello.txt -importpath wiggy.net/hello ... (remaining 12 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
compilepkg: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_wichert/e7573342ee9452df4c3dfa671d399a16/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/76/execroot/__main__/hello.go:8:12: could not embed hello.txt: no matching files found
INFO: Elapsed time: 0,112s, Critical Path: 0,04s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: The embeddable file(s) must be next to the source files, not in the `bin` folder.

Comment: That leads to the question of how to get the generated file next to the source file. I haven't been able to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: the trick is to use `genrule` to generate the file(s) to be embedded, and then use `go_embed_data` to embed them. A work `BUILD.bazel` looks like this:

```
genrule(
    name = "hellodata",
    srcs = ["hello.go"],
    outs = ["hello.txt"],
    cmd = "cat $(SRCS) | tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m > $@",
)

go_embed_data(
    name = "hello_embed",
    src = ":hellodata",
    package = "hello",
    var = "greeting",
)

go_library(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = [
        "hello.go",
        ":hello_embed",
    ],
    importpath = "wiggy.net/hello",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed `-embedsrc bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/hello.txt` in the command line for the failing action in your question, so as a hunch I tried the equivalent on my machine:

```
//go:embed bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/hello.txt
var greeting []byte
```

And that seemed to work.

This is not so great because configuration information gets embedded in the source files (indeed, on your mac machine it's `darwin_arm64-fastbuild` and on my linux machine it's `k8-fastbuild`), so now your source code is artificially platform dependent.

It looks like this feature is relatively new (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/2775, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/2986). I would file an issue with rules_go about this.

There also appears to be `go_embed_data` which might behave differently:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/docs/go/extras/extras.md#go_embed_data